# Add event handler to ASP.net web control without the designer

Tags: asp.net, webforms, event-handling, web-control

Is there a convenient way to add an event handler to a web control declaratively (as an attribute on the control in markup) without needing to select the control in the design view for the .aspx/.ascx? Not only would I prefer to avoid the design view, but it is incapable of showing controls properly in many otherwise completely innocuous situations.

I really wonder why the properties panel is so different depending on whether the selection of the control is in the designer view or in the source view.

Comment: BTW: I am finding that the fastest way is to add the handler in code with auto-complete, then to remove the original attachment and copy the method signature for the handler into the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview this scenario has been improved:

> Creating event handlers for ASP.NET controls have gotten significantly
>   easier in Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview. Developers no longer
>   have to write the event handlers and hook them up manually, which
>   saves a lot of time.
>
> IntelliSense for all server-side events now include a value called
>   “” which, as the name implies, will create an event
>   handler with the right signature in the code-behind file.
>
> [image]

Source: [New HTML Editor feature in Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2011/09/20/new-html-editor-feature-in-visual-studio-11-developer-preview.aspx)